# Synchronizing banner execution

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, ads, banner

I'm looking for a best practice to synchronize 3 separate flash banners displayed on the same page.

Basically all of them need to preload (politely), notify they're all prepared after what a command would somehow launch the animation of the 3 of them synchronously making them act like one and single add.

The solution needs to be x-browser.

For now I can only picture a LocalConnection for the intercommunication ?

Any expert advices or hints would be welcome !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalConnection is definitely the way I'd go, but you could also have a JavaScript controller that communicates with all three SWFs (via ExternalInterface). I don't think there are any other likely possibilities besides those two methods.

Make sure that you account for the possibility that banner A might (in theory) finish loading before banner C has initialized enough to receive LocalConnection or ExternalInterface calls.